# Getting 'GLIBCXX_3.4.30 not found' error in RStudio after creating new R environment with mamba on Ubuntu 20.04 - How to fix it?

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio, conda, mamba

I just installed mamba to create a new R environment. So, I ran `mamba create -n myenv -c conda-forge -c bioconda r-seurat=4* "bioconductor-genomeinfodbdata=1.2.7" bioconductor-deseq2`. On the other hand, I installed the RStudio version 2022.02.0 "Prairie Trillium" for my Ubuntu 20.04.
**The thing is, when I open RStudio outside the environment works just fine. But when I activate the environment and run `rstudio` an error window appears** (this is the first time I'm getting that window in RStudio) with the following error:

```
`/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rsession: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.30 not found (required by /home/myuser/mambaforge/envs/myenv/lib/R/lib/../../libicuuc.so.72)`
```

When using this command `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` this is the output:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

But I have a newer version in mambaforge `strings ~/mambaforge/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`:

```
strings ~/mambaforge/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

So, I used `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/anaconda3/lib` and also `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/mambaforge/lib` but didn't work.

I also tried the following, but didn't work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libstdc++6
```

I also tried following these instructions https://bioconda.github.io/ so I configured the channels using:

```
conda config --add channels defaults
conda config --add channels bioconda
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

This is the `mamba list`:

```
# packages in environment at /home/ezequielp/mambaforge/envs/dashboard_1:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
_r-mutex                  1.0.1               anacondar_1    conda-forge
binutils_impl_linux-64    2.40                 hf600244_0    conda-forge
bioconductor-annotate     1.72.0            r41hdfd78af_0    bioconda
bioconductor-annotationdbi 1.56.2            r41hdfd78af_0    bioconda
bioconductor-apeglm       1.16.0            r41hc247a5b_2    bioconda
bioconductor-biobase      2.54.0            r41hc0cfd56_2    bioconda
bioconductor-biocgenerics 0.40.0            r41hdfd78af_0    bioconda
bioconductor-biocparallel 1.28.3            r41hc247a5b_1    bioconda
bioconductor-biostrings   2.62.0            r41hc0cfd56_2    bioconda
bioconductor-delayedarray 0.20.0            r41hc0cfd56_2    bioconda
bioconductor-deseq2       1.34.0            r41hc247a5b_3    bioconda
bioconductor-genefilter   1.76.0            r41h38f54d8_2    bioconda
bioconductor-geneplotter  1.72.0            r41hdfd78af_0    bioconda
bioconductor-genomeinfodb 1.30.1            r41hdfd78af_0    bioconda
bioconductor-genomeinfodbdata 1.2.7             r41hdfd78af_2    bioconda
bioconductor-genomicranges 1.46.1            r41hc0cfd56_1    bioconda
bioconductor-iranges      2.28.0            r41hc0cfd56_2    bioconda
bioconductor-keggrest     1.34.0            r41hdfd78af_0    bioconda
bioconductor-matrixgenerics 1.6.0             r41hdfd78af_0    bioconda
bioconductor-s4vectors    0.32.4            r41hc0cfd56_0    bioconda
bioconductor-summarizedexperiment 1.24.0            r41hdfd78af_0    bioconda
bioconductor-xvector      0.34.0            r41hc0cfd56_2    bioconda
bioconductor-zlibbioc     1.40.0            r41hc0cfd56_2    bioconda
bwidget                   1.9.14               ha770c72_1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7f98852_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.19.1               hd590300_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.5.7             hbcca054_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            hbbf8b49_1016    conda-forge
curl                      8.1.2                h409715c_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.5.0                hcb278e6_1    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.14.2               h14ed4e7_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               hca18f0e_1    conda-forge
fribidi                   1.0.10               h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
gcc_impl_linux-64         12.2.0              hcc96c02_19    conda-forge
geos                      3.11.2               hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
gettext                   0.21.1               h27087fc_0    conda-forge
gfortran_impl_linux-64    12.2.0              h55be85b_19    conda-forge
glpk                      5.0                  h445213a_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.2.1                h58526e2_0    conda-forge
graphite2                 1.3.13            h58526e2_1001    conda-forge
gsl                       2.7                  he838d99_0    conda-forge
gxx_impl_linux-64         12.2.0              hcc96c02_19    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  7.3.0                hdb3a94d_0    conda-forge
icu                       72.1                 hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
kernel-headers_linux-64   2.6.32              he073ed8_15    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.20.1               h81ceb04_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.40                 h41732ed_0    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           16_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           16_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libcurl                   8.1.2                h409715c_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.18                 h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.5.0                hcb278e6_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc-devel_linux-64     12.2.0              h3b97bd3_19    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 12.2.0              h65d4601_19    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            12.2.0              h69a702a_19    conda-forge
libgfortran5              12.2.0              h337968e_19    conda-forge
libglib                   2.76.3               hebfc3b9_0    conda-forge
libgomp                   12.2.0              h65d4601_19    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libjpeg-turbo             2.1.5.1              h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           16_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.52.0               h61bc06f_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.21          pthreads_h78a6416_3    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h753d276_0    conda-forge
libsanitizer              12.2.0              h46fd767_19    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.10.0               hf14f497_3    conda-forge
libstdcxx-devel_linux-64  12.2.0              h3b97bd3_19    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              12.2.0              h46fd767_19    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.0                ha587672_6    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.0                h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.15                 h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.11.4               h0d562d8_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h166bdaf_4    conda-forge
make                      4.3                  hd18ef5c_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.3                  h27087fc_1    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.1                hd590300_1    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.19.2               h32600fe_2    conda-forge
pango                     1.50.14              heaa33ce_1    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.40                hc3806b6_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.40.0               h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
r-abind                   1.4_5           r41hc72bb7e_1004    conda-forge
r-ashr                    2.2_54            r41h7525677_1    conda-forge
r-askpass                 1.1               r41h06615bd_3    conda-forge
r-backports               1.4.1             r41h06615bd_1    conda-forge
r-base                    4.1.3                hfabd6f2_9    conda-forge
r-base64enc               0.1_3           r41h06615bd_1005    conda-forge
r-bbmle                   1.0.25            r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-bdsmatrix               1.3_6             r41h06615bd_1    conda-forge
r-bh                      1.81.0_1          r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-bit                     4.0.5             r41h06615bd_0    conda-forge
r-bit64                   4.0.5             r41h06615bd_1    conda-forge
r-bitops                  1.0_7             r41h06615bd_1    conda-forge
r-blob                    1.2.4             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-bslib                   0.4.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-cachem                  1.0.8             r41h57805ef_0    conda-forge
r-catools                 1.18.2            r41h7525677_1    conda-forge
r-cli                     3.6.1             r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-cluster                 2.1.4             r41h8da6f51_0    conda-forge
r-coda                    0.19_4            r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-codetools               0.2_19            r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-colorspace              2.1_0             r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-commonmark              1.9.0             r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-cowplot                 1.1.1             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-cpp11                   0.4.3             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-crayon                  1.5.2             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-crosstalk               1.2.0             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-curl                    4.3.3             r41hf9611b0_2    conda-forge
r-data.table              1.14.8            r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-dbi                     1.1.3             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-deldir                  1.0_9             r41h61816a4_0    conda-forge
r-digest                  0.6.31            r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-dplyr                   1.1.2             r41ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-dqrng                   0.3.0             r41h7525677_1    conda-forge
r-ellipsis                0.3.2             r41h06615bd_1    conda-forge
r-emdbook                 1.3.12            r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-etrunct                 0.1             r41hc72bb7e_1004    conda-forge
r-evaluate                0.21              r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-fansi                   1.0.4             r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-farver                  2.1.1             r41h7525677_1    conda-forge
r-fastmap                 1.1.1             r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-fitdistrplus            1.1_11            r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-fnn                     1.1.3.2           r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-fontawesome             0.5.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-formatr                 1.14              r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-fs                      1.6.2             r41ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-futile.logger           1.4.3           r41hc72bb7e_1004    conda-forge
r-futile.options          1.0.1           r41hc72bb7e_1003    conda-forge
r-future                  1.32.0            r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-future.apply            1.11.0            r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-generics                0.1.3             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-ggplot2                 3.4.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-ggrepel                 0.9.3             r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-ggridges                0.5.4             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-globals                 0.16.2            r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-glue                    1.6.2             r41h06615bd_1    conda-forge
r-goftest                 1.2_3             r41h06615bd_1    conda-forge
r-gplots                  3.1.3             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-gridextra               2.3             r41hc72bb7e_1004    conda-forge
r-gtable                  0.3.3             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-gtools                  3.9.4             r41h06615bd_0    conda-forge
r-here                    1.0.1             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-hexbin                  1.28.3            r41hac0b197_0    conda-forge
r-highr                   0.10              r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-htmltools               0.5.5             r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-htmlwidgets             1.6.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-httpuv                  1.6.11            r41ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-httr                    1.4.6             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-ica                     1.0_3             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-igraph                  1.4.3             r41h9254619_0    conda-forge
r-invgamma                1.1               r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-irlba                   2.3.5.1           r41h5f7b363_0    conda-forge
r-isoband                 0.2.7             r41h38f115c_1    conda-forge
r-jquerylib               0.1.4             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-jsonlite                1.8.4             r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-kernsmooth              2.23_21           r41h13b3f57_0    conda-forge
r-knitr                   1.43              r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-labeling                0.4.2             r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-lambda.r                1.2.4             r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-later                   1.3.1             r41ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-lattice                 0.21_8            r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-lazyeval                0.2.2             r41h06615bd_3    conda-forge
r-leiden                  0.4.3             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-lifecycle               1.0.3             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-listenv                 0.9.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-lmtest                  0.9_40            r41h8da6f51_1    conda-forge
r-locfit                  1.5_9.7           r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-lsei                    1.3_0             r41hc3ea6d6_2    conda-forge
r-magrittr                2.0.3             r41h06615bd_1    conda-forge
r-mass                    7.3_58.3          r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-matrix                  1.5_4.1           r41h316c678_0    conda-forge
r-matrixstats             0.63.0            r41h06615bd_0    conda-forge
r-memoise                 2.0.1             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-mgcv                    1.8_42            r41he1ae0d6_0    conda-forge
r-mime                    0.12              r41h06615bd_1    conda-forge
r-miniui                  0.1.1.1         r41hc72bb7e_1003    conda-forge
r-mixsqp                  0.3_48            r41h9f5de39_0    conda-forge
r-munsell                 0.5.0           r41hc72bb7e_1005    conda-forge
r-mvtnorm                 1.1_3             r41h8da6f51_1    conda-forge
r-nlme                    3.1_162           r41hac0b197_0    conda-forge
r-npsurv                  0.5_0             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-numderiv                2016.8_1.1        r41hc72bb7e_4    conda-forge
r-openssl                 2.0.6             r41habfbb5e_0    conda-forge
r-parallelly              1.36.0            r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-patchwork               1.1.2             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-pbapply                 1.7_0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-pillar                  1.9.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-pkgconfig               2.0.3             r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-plogr                   0.2.0           r41hc72bb7e_1004    conda-forge
r-plotly                  4.10.1            r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-plyr                    1.8.8             r41h7525677_0    conda-forge
r-png                     0.1_8             r41h10cf519_0    conda-forge
r-polyclip                1.10_4            r41h7525677_0    conda-forge
r-progressr               0.13.0            r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-promises                1.2.0.1           r41h7525677_1    conda-forge
r-purrr                   1.0.1             r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-r6                      2.5.1             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-rann                    2.6.1             r41h7525677_3    conda-forge
r-rappdirs                0.3.3             r41h06615bd_1    conda-forge
r-rcolorbrewer            1.1_3             r41h785f33e_1    conda-forge
r-rcpp                    1.0.10            r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-rcppannoy               0.0.20            r41h7525677_0    conda-forge
r-rcpparmadillo           0.12.4.0.0        r41h08d816e_0    conda-forge
r-rcppeigen               0.3.3.9.3         r41h9f5de39_0    conda-forge
r-rcppnumerical           0.5_0             r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-rcppparallel            5.1.6             r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-rcppprogress            0.4.2             r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-rcpptoml                0.2.2             r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-rcurl                   1.98_1.12         r41hf9611b0_1    conda-forge
r-reshape2                1.4.4             r41h7525677_2    conda-forge
r-reticulate              1.28              r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-rgeos                   0.6_3             r41h214e639_0    conda-forge
r-rlang                   1.1.1             r41ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-rmarkdown               2.21              r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-rocr                    1.0_11            r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-rprojroot               2.0.3             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-rspectra                0.16_1            r41h9f5de39_1    conda-forge
r-rsqlite                 2.3.1             r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-rtsne                   0.16              r41h37cf8d7_1    conda-forge
r-sass                    0.4.6             r41ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-scales                  1.2.1             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-scattermore             1.1               r41ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-sctransform             0.3.5             r41h9f5de39_1    conda-forge
r-seurat                  4.3.0             r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-seuratobject            4.1.3             r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-shiny                   1.7.4             r41h785f33e_0    conda-forge
r-sitmo                   2.0.2             r41h7525677_1    conda-forge
r-snow                    0.4_4             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-sourcetools             0.1.7_1           r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-sp                      1.6_1             r41h57805ef_0    conda-forge
r-spatstat.data           3.0_1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-spatstat.explore        3.2_1             r41h57805ef_0    conda-forge
r-spatstat.geom           3.2_1             r41h57805ef_0    conda-forge
r-spatstat.random         3.1_5             r41ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-spatstat.sparse         3.0_1             r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-spatstat.utils          3.0_3             r41h57805ef_0    conda-forge
r-squarem                 2021.1            r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-stringi                 1.7.12            r41hc0c3e09_1    conda-forge
r-stringr                 1.5.0             r41h785f33e_0    conda-forge
r-survival                3.5_5             r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-sys                     3.4.2             r41h57805ef_0    conda-forge
r-tensor                  1.5             r41hc72bb7e_1004    conda-forge
r-tibble                  3.2.1             r41h133d619_1    conda-forge
r-tidyr                   1.3.0             r41h38f115c_0    conda-forge
r-tidyselect              1.2.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-tinytex                 0.45              r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-truncnorm               1.0_9             r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-utf8                    1.2.3             r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-uwot                    0.1.14            r41h7525677_1    conda-forge
r-vctrs                   0.6.2             r41ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-viridislite             0.4.1             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-withr                   2.5.0             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-xfun                    0.39              r41ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-xml                     3.99_0.14         r41hc38eee6_1    conda-forge
r-xtable                  1.8_4             r41hc72bb7e_4    conda-forge
r-yaml                    2.3.7             r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-zoo                     1.8_12            r41h133d619_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h8228510_1    conda-forge
sed                       4.8                  he412f7d_0    conda-forge
sysroot_linux-64          2.12                he073ed8_15    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h27826a3_0    conda-forge
tktable                   2.10                 hb7b940f_3    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.0.10               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.3             hd9c2040_1000    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.8.4                h8ee46fc_1    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.11               hd590300_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.4                h0b41bf4_2    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.10            h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
xorg-libxt                1.3.0                hd590300_0    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1            h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0             h0b41bf4_1003    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31            h7f98852_1007    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               h166bdaf_4    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.2                h3eb15da_6    conda-forge
```

Comment: Actually, on second thought: I see the issue is more that when running in RStudio it is resolving to the system libstdc++. Sorry I was too hasty. Still, interested to know if it works outside RStudio - i.e., is RStudio doing something weird to the library loading. Testing, I see everything resolves correctly to the environment libs in a Mambaforge Docker container, but that's not with RStudio.

Comment: Yes, I don't know. I didn't say this but I also reinstalled RStudio and even selected other versions but that didn't work either @merv

Comment: Yeess I found the error @merv . I used export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/mambaforge/lib but outside the environment and I have to use it inside of it

Comment: But why isn’t it respecting the @rpath directive that specifies to first look relative to the depending object? That should be priority and never need to fall back on LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I’d like to see a full `mamba list` for the environment. Current solution of pointing back to **base** lib/ is prone to further problems.

Comment: Yes, the current solution is not good at all. It's just the only one I found after 1 and a half weeks of trying. Right now I left the output of mamba list. Another problem I ran into is that now I can open RStudio but when I enter it I can't activate any of the packages that mamba supposedly installed. I'm sure it has to do with the fact that somehow several paths were broken and I might have to format the OS. @merv

Comment: Yeah, I'm baffled - environment-wise looks all good.